# Who is this artist?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

[image: artist 1]

[image: artist 2]

Any help will be appreciated, am lost

Answer (score 0):

[image: 蜀南畫]

> 蜀南畫
>
> Drawn/painted by 蜀南

[image: 天瑤 博陵劉氏]

> 天瑤
>
> (Artist's given name)
>
> 博陵劉氏
>
> 劉 clan of 博陵 prefecture

I don't think the two pictures reference the same artist. The second picture seems to reference an artist which has done other paintings up for sale (e.g. https://www.mincang.net/jianding/zihua-254043.html).

Comment: Thank you so much @dROOOze. Amazing how you can decipher he words, once you did everything seems clearer now.

Comment: the link provided said it’s “博**陵**”, not “林” lah 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 ooops sorry typo!

Comment: @JananTan If interested it is mainly just practice, so you can learn it too! Basically these things are just written in old fashioned fonts, like trying to read the declaration of independence in english ☺